# Python battleship, double the trouble

Tags: python, project

Why does it ask you twice where you want to put you battleship?
I have no clue way is does what it does.

Anyway in this link you can see the full code, because I don't know if that is necessary. http://speedy.sh/QYJWp/battleship-goed.txt

I think that the problem occurs before the `//_________________________________________________________//` part

```
    board1 = []
    board2 = []


    for x in range(10):
        board1.append(["O"] * 10)

    for x in range(10):
        board2.append(["O"] * 10)

    def print_board1(board):
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(row)
    def print_board2(board):
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(row)

    print "Board User 1"
    print_board1(board1)
    print "----------------------------------------------"
    print "Board User 2"
    print_board2(board2)

    print "Let's play Battleship!"
    print "Try to destroy all your opponents battleship!"
    print"Good luck!"
    print " "
    print " "


    def U1_Input_row1(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what row do you want to place your first ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_row1(board1)

    def U1_Input_col1(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what col do you want to place your first ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_col1(board1)

    ship1 = [U1_Input_row1(board1), U1_Input_col1(board1)] 

    def U1_Input_row2(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what row do you want to place your second ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_row2(board1)

    def U1_Input_col2(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what col do you want to place your second ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_col2(board1)

    ship2 = [U1_Input_row2(board1), U1_Input_col2(board1)]

    def U1_Input_row3(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what row do you want to place your third ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_row3(board1)

    def U1_Input_col3(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what col do you want to place your third ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_col3(board1)

    ship3 = [U1_Input_row3(board1), U1_Input_col3(board1)]

    def U1_Input_row4(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what row do you want to place your fourth ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_row4(board1)

    def U1_Input_col4(board1):
                x = float(raw_input("User 1, in what col do you want to place your fourth ship?"))
                if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
                    return x - 1
                else:
                    print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
                    U1_Input_col4(board1)

    ship4 = [U1_Input_row4(board1), U1_Input_col4(board1)] 

    if ship1 == ship2 or ship1 == ship3 or ship1 == ship4 or ship2 == ship3 or ship2 == ship4 or ship3 == ship4:
                print "YOU CANT PLACE 2 SHIPS IN THE SAME SPOT"
                U1_Input_row1(board1)
                U1_Input_col1(board1)
                U1_Input_row2(board1)
                U1_Input_col2(board1)
                U1_Input_row3(board1)
                U1_Input_col3(board1) 
                U1_Input_row4(board1) 
                U1_Input_col4(board1) 


    def U2_Input_row1(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what row do you want to place your first ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_row1(board2)

    def U2_Input_col1(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what col do you want to place your first ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_col1(board2)

    ship1u2 = [U2_Input_row1(board1), U2_Input_col1(board1)] 

    def U2_Input_row2(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what row do you want to place your second ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_row2(board2)

    def U2_Input_col2(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what col do you want to place your second ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_col2(board2)

    ship2u2 = [U2_Input_row2(board1), U2_Input_col2(board1)]

    def U2_Input_row3(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what row do you want to place your third ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_row3(board2)

    def U2_Input_col3(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what col do you want to place your third ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_col3(board2)

    ship3u2 = [U2_Input_row3(board1), U2_Input_col3(board1)]

    def U2_Input_row4(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what row do you want to place your fourth ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_row4(board2)

    def U2_Input_col4(board2):
        x = float(raw_input("User 2, in what col do you want to place your fourth ship?"))
        if x > 0 and x < 11 and x%1 == 0:
            return x - 1
        else:
            print "Please enter an integer and a number between 1 and 10"
            U2_Input_col4(board2)

    ship4u2 = [U2_Input_row4(board1), U2_Input_col4(board1)]

    if ship1u2 == ship2u2 or ship1u2 == ship3u2 or ship1u2 == ship4u2 or ship2u2 == ship3u2 or ship2u2 == ship4u2 or ship3u2 == ship4u2:
                print "YOU CANT PLACE 2 SHIPS IN THE SAME SPOT"
                U2_Input_row1(board2)
                U2_Input_col1(board2)
                U2_Input_row2(board2)
                U2_Input_col2(board2)
                U2_Input_row3(board2)
                U2_Input_col3(board2) 
                U2_Input_row4(board2) 
                U2_Input_col4(board2)


    U1_Input_row1 = U1_Input_row1(board1)
    U1_Input_col1 = U1_Input_col1(board1)
    U1_Input_row2 = U1_Input_row2(board1)
    U1_Input_col2 = U1_Input_col2(board1)
    U1_Input_row3 = U1_Input_row3(board1)
    U1_Input_col3 = U1_Input_col3(board1)
    U1_Input_row4 = U1_Input_row4(board1)
    U1_Input_col4 = U1_Input_col4(board1)
    U2_Input_row1 = U2_Input_row1(board2)
    U2_Input_col1 = U2_Input_col1(board2)
    U2_Input_row2 = U2_Input_row2(board2)
    U2_Input_col2 = U2_Input_col2(board2)
    U2_Input_row3 = U2_Input_row3(board2)
    U2_Input_col3 = U2_Input_col3(board2)
    U2_Input_row4 = U2_Input_row4(board2)
    U2_Input_col4 = U2_Input_col4(board2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking it twice because it goes through the script and hits these between the functions:

```
ship1 = [U1_Input_row1(board1), U1_Input_col1(board1)]
ship2 = [U1_Input_row2(board1), U1_Input_col2(board1)]
ship3 = [U1_Input_row3(board1), U1_Input_col3(board1)]
ship4 = [U1_Input_row4(board1), U1_Input_col4(board1)]
ship1u2 = [U2_Input_row1(board1), U2_Input_col1(board1)]
ship2u2 = [U2_Input_row2(board1), U2_Input_col2(board1)]
ship3u2 = [U2_Input_row3(board1), U2_Input_col3(board1)]
ship4u2 = [U2_Input_row4(board1), U2_Input_col4(board1)]
```

Then at the end it asks for input again with these calls:

```
U1_Input_row1 = U1_Input_row1(board1)
U1_Input_col1 = U1_Input_col1(board1)
U1_Input_row2 = U1_Input_row2(board1)
U1_Input_col2 = U1_Input_col2(board1)
U1_Input_row3 = U1_Input_row3(board1)
U1_Input_col3 = U1_Input_col3(board1)
U1_Input_row4 = U1_Input_row4(board1)
U1_Input_col4 = U1_Input_col4(board1)
U2_Input_row1 = U2_Input_row1(board2)
U2_Input_col1 = U2_Input_col1(board2)
U2_Input_row2 = U2_Input_row2(board2)
U2_Input_col2 = U2_Input_col2(board2)
U2_Input_row3 = U2_Input_row3(board2)
U2_Input_col3 = U2_Input_col3(board2)
U2_Input_row4 = U2_Input_row4(board2)
U2_Input_col4 = U2_Input_col4(board2)
```

The script is poorly thought out though, as most of these functions could have just been stuffed into a single function to save fewer lines of code.

This would be annoying for the user since he would have to go through the whole process of inputting ship positions even though 7/8 of them were ok.

```
if ship1u2 == ship2u2 or ship1u2 == ship3u2 or ship1u2 == ship4u2 or ship2u2 == ship3u2 or ship2u2 == ship4u2 or ship3u2 == ship4u2:
```

You can also use `while` statement to keep asking a question if the user inputs something wrong. The way it's being done now is a bit weird.

If the user inputs a bunch of letters or whatnot the script will crash right away because there's no error checking there. The use of `isdigit()` can help determine if the input is an integer before converting to `int`, and a `try` `except` can be use if the field is simply left empty.

Hope this helps out :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where it would do what you described, but I think you should use an array instead of doing ship1u1... It would make it a lot easier to read your code and it would save you a couple lines.

Comment: This is the greatest non-answer :)